# TableLayoutControl DragNDrop Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, treeview

I have a Treeview and listbox control on a form. 
Dropping items from the TreeView onto the ListBox is handled with the following method:

```
void ListBoxDrop(Dictionary<string, string> datasource, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
            Point targetPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            // Retrieve the listBox at the drop location. (This is where it sees a TableLayoutControl)       
            object controlAtPoint = this.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint);
            if (!(controlAtPoint is ListBox))
                return;

            ListBox targetListbox = this.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint) as ListBox;

            // Retrieve the node that was dragged.
            TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

            // Only add the item if it doesnt already exist in the list.             
            if (!datasource.ContainsKey(draggedNode.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                datasource.Add(draggedNode.Tag.ToString(), draggedNode.Text);
            }
        }
```

The issue is when I drag a TableLayoutPanel from the containers toolbox onto my form and then move the ListBox into one of the TableLayoutPanel cells. 
What happens now when dragging from the TreeView to the Listbox is that the this.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint) returns the TableLayoutPanel control reference instead of the ListBox control.

Is there some way to get this.GetChildAtPoint to return the listbox instead of its container control ?

Dankie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change your `this` to the TableLayoutPanel control:

```
Point targetPoint = tlp.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
object controlAtPoint = tlp.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint);
if (!(controlAtPoint is ListBox))
  return;
ListBox targetListbox = tlp.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint) as ListBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

GetChildAtPoint() doesn't do what you hope it does.  It doesn't iterate through the nested controls and find the deepest nested control.  It only looks at the children of *this*, your form.  So getting the TableLayoutPanel back is the expected outcome.

So could iterate it yourself, like this:

```
    Control box = this;
    do {
        var targetPoint = box.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        box = box.GetChildAtPoint(targetPoint);
        if (box == null) return;
    } while (!(box is ListBox));
```